# Output from large .csv files generated by Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am downloading some data in static and time series format using Matlab codes (and toolboxes). The codes give out the results by default in a .csv file for static and time series separately. Although the static data turns out fine, the time series data is huge and the .csv file doesn't load all the data. I tried changing the output file extension to .dta and then also .mat in order to view the output in Stata or Matlab. Also tried writing a little loop where the data loaded into large .csv file can be split into two worksheets within the same file. But none of it has worked. Although I am used to some basic coding in Matlab, I am new to dealing with such large datasets. Any help on this would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you- Veronica

Comment: What do you mean by `the csv file doesn't load all the data`? It doesn't contain all the data? Are you on a Windows FAT32 filesystem that doesn't support files over 2GB maybe? Is your filesystem full? How many lines does the csv contain? How big is your output file? In bytes? And in lines? (Use `wc -l file.csv` on Linux)

Comment: The csv contains all the data, but I cannot view all the data in csv file due to limited number of rows. The output file is quite big with 1135089 rows and the csv file displays 1048576 rows. I cannot view rest of the output. In terms of bytes the file is 80MB. Tried alternative ways of viewing the full output but didn't work. It doesn't seem like a Windows filesystem issue. Thanks!-Veronica

Comment: What is the actual problem? You have all the data in the CSV but you cannot see it - is that it? If so, what tool are you using to try and look at it?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is the problem. I am unable to view all the output as the CSV file limits it. It seemed like a trivial problem initially. But none of the things I tried worked. I tried saving it as a .dta file to view it in Stata writing a little loop where the data loaded into large CSV file can be split into two worksheets within the same file. I would ideally like to have it all loaded in a CSV, separate worksheets within the same file. e.g. since CSV displays 1048576 rows, these can go in 1st worksheet and remaining rows continued in next worksheet (same CSV file). Thanks!

Comment: What program are you using to view the CSV file?

Comment: I am currently using Microsoft Excel to open and view the file.

Comment: By the way, changing the extension of a file does not change the format. It's like calling a dump truck a "sandwich" and then trying to eat it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using these two bits of VBScript to split your CSV file into 2 pieces. There will be 599,999 lines in the first output file (`part1.csv`) and the rest in the second file (`part2.csv`).

Save this as `part1.vbs`

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1) 
LineNum=1

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   REM Read in next line of input
   Line  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   If LineNum<600000 Then
      stdout.WriteLine(Line)
   End If
   LineNum=LineNum+1
Loop
```

Save this as `part2.vbs`

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1) 
LineNum=1

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   REM Read in next line of input
   Line  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   If LineNum>=600000 Then
      stdout.WriteLine(Line)
   End If
   LineNum=LineNum+1
Loop
```

Then you can do this at the Command Prompt to split your file in two:

```
cscript /nologo part1.vbs  YourFile.CSV  > part1.csv
cscript /nologo part2.vbs  YourFile.CSV  > part2.csv
```